# Py3o.template : How to increment py3o variable inside a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I'm working on .odt report using py3o.template in Odoo. 
In the report, I need to add a number in a Group, so if I have 3 groups, It should print out : 
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
I did it like in this image :
[image]
It doesn't work and I get these errors :

> "Could not move siblings for '%s'" % py3o_base
>   py3o.template.main.TemplateException: Could not move siblings for
>   'with="i=1"'

Can you help me?
PS : I need to call "i" between Group and [date_start]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when you did not have close properly your tags.

I can see only one closing `with`, try to close the two others.

***Check the following example:***

```
with="index=1"
    with="index=index+1"
        with="index=index+1"
            function="index"  index=3
        /with
        function="index" index=2
    /with
    function="index" index=1
/with

function="index" index undefined
```

> Note that if a variable of the same name already existed outside of the scope of the with directive, it will not be overwritten. Instead, it will have the same value it had prior to the with assignment. Effectively, this means that variables are immutable.

To avoid that we can use a list to hold indexes and in each iteration we will create a new variable to hold the new index (we can use list.pop(0) to remove the previous index).

```
with="index=[1]"
  for="item in range(4)"
    function="index[-1]"

    with="_=index.append(index[-1]+1)"
    /with

    with="_=index.pop(0)"
    /with

  /for

At the end index = function="str(index)"
/with
```

The output should be:

```
1
2
3
4
At the end index == [5]
```

To enumerate the loop items I highly recommend using enumerate function.

```
for="index,d in enumerate(o.get_session_date_ids(), 1)"
function="index"
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I did it like you said, with 3 "with" link. The "i" doesn't take account the loop and the encrementation and print Group 2, Group 2, ....

Comment: Do you need to enumerate loop items?

Comment: I recommend you [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), check my edit.

Comment: OMG, and I didn't think of it, krrrrr. Thank you very much